# Accessing hidden input array using ajax / php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a form that contains several of the following types of elements

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected_models[]" value="1">1</td>
<input type="hidden" name="selected_models[]" value="2">2</td>
<input type="hidden" name="selected_models[]" value="3">3</td>
<input type="hidden" name="selected_models[]" value="4">4</td>
```

I am trying to pass this array, along with all my other form data to a jQuery $.post function, but I can't access the data in php correctly.

I've tried to pass it using the following (jQuery):

```
var _data = { models: $('input[name="selected_models[]"]').serialize() }
```

and then access it in PHP using:

```
$models = $_POST['models'];
```

just for the purpose of trying to check the data, I pass this variable to the ajax response, and log it back to the console using:

```
Php
$response = jseon_encode( 
    array(
        'success' => true,
        'models' => json_encode($models)
    ) 
);
```

and

```
JS
console.log(JSON.parse(response.models)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
selected_models%5B%5D=37&selected_models%5B%5D=51&selected_models%5B%5D=57
```

so, honestly now I'm just stuck with how to loop through those values in php so I can actually do something with them. Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```
Php
foreach ( $models as $model ) {
    $id = $model.selected_models
    // Do more stuff
}
```

But this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can i see the html form?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this in jQuery and passing a parsed value to PHP, instead:

```
var uniqueModels = [];

if ( document.getElementById('acInheritFromVehicle').checked ) {
    var models = jQuery( 'input[name="selected_models[]"]:checked');
    var modelIDs = [];

    //console.log(models);

    models.each(function() {
        if( jQuery.inArray( ))
        modelIDs.push( jQuery(this).val() );
    });

    uniqueModels = unique(modelIDs);

    uniqueModels = jQuery.grep( uniqueModels, function(value) {
        return value != 0
    });

    //console.log(uniqueModels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing it correctly, just some minor PHP tweaks and you would have got it. Once you serialize your data and sent to PHP you can always check what that array looks like by using `print_r($models)` function.

To loop through your `$models` array, do the following:

```js
foreach($models as $model) {
  echo 'Value of hidden input is: ' . $model;
  echo '<br />';
}
```

`$model` will represent an actual value received through PHP request. [Check out this example](http://pc-technic.blogspot.ca/2010/10/php-how-to-use-multiple-combo-boxes.html)